# Limitando quantidade de matches do regex com Python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy, scraping

estou com uma certa dificuldade, gostaria de criar um `for` no `Python` para retornar uma quantidade específica de `match` do `regex`.

Da maneira que fiz, ele está retornando todos os `links` que existem e que atendem o padrão definido da página, porém, gostaria de capturar somente a quantidade que necessito, independente se a página tiver `10`, `20` ou `30` `links`, somente executar na quantidade que estiver definida, podendo ser `1`, `2`, `n` - uma variável a ser setada por exemplo `numbers_articles`.

Segue código:

```
# padrão regex para encontrar links de artigo
pattern = re.compile(r'https?:\/\/meiobit\.com\/[\d]+\/[A-Za-z0-9-]+\/')

# lista para armazenar os links capturados
article_links = []

# mexer neste for para retornar uma quantidade específica informada
for match in re.finditer(pattern, page_content):
    article_links.append(match.group(0))
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sempre que estiver trabalhando com iteradores, lembre-se do pacote [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Você pode utilizar a função [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) para limitar o iterador retornado por `re.finditer`. Por exemplo:

```
from itertools import islice

# padrão regex para encontrar links de artigo
pattern = re.compile(r'https?:\/\/meiobit\.com\/[\d]+\/[A-Za-z0-9-]+\/')

# lista para armazenar os links capturados
article_links = []
number_articles = 5
articles = islice(re.finditer(pattern, page_content), number_articles)

# mexer neste for para retornar uma quantidade específica informada
for match in articles:
    article_links.append(match.group(0))
```

A saída possuirá, no máximo, 5 registros.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção e explicação sobre uma solução @Anderson. Vou fazer as alterações no código, pois esta resposta funcionou como o esperado.